# How to map sorting fields of Pageable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I know I can map `page` and `size` fields for `Pageable` ex.

`http://example.com/foo?page=0&size=10`

but how can I **sort direction** and **sort field**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.

Basically, you can do it like

`<url>/?page=0&size=20&sort=id,desc`

or the following for multiple sort options

`<url>/?page=0&size=20&sort=id,desc&sort=name`

Comment: Is there a way to extrack the sorting from the response ? Say, we don't have it in the request because it is a default sorting specified server side.

Comment: @Stephane yes, you can extend PageImpl class, let's say it will be CustomPage<T> . and inside constructor we can copy all sort fields with directions. example:
public class CustomPage<T> extends PageImpl<T> {
    private final List<Sort.Order> sortDirection;

    public CustomPage(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total) {
        super(content, pageable, total);
        this.sortDirection = pageable.getSort().get().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
//getter
}
and for request:  in response you will get requested sorting params.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I try to find the official documentation related to how to map the url parameters to the Pageable, but I couldn't find it so far, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

just add to your endpoint

```
http://example.com/foo?page=0&size=10&sort={ASC/DESC}&field={fieldname}
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. What I need is automatic mapping to `Pageable`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do this while submitting your query

```
 PageRequest request = new PageRequest(page,1,Sort.Direction.ASC,"country");
```

So according to that you can pass your parameter

Comment: Thanks. I know about this but what I need is automatic mapping to `Pageable` like `page` and `size`.